# F2A85V-PRO motherboard with AMD A10-5800K processor issue with linux systems

Tags: ati, asus, system-installation, compatibility, cpu

Since I bought my new machine - F2A85-V PRO motherboard, AMD A10-5800K processor and 16GB CORSAIR RAM, Im facing problems with installing every x64 based linux distribution. But not only installing. X86 systems run well but not all. Ive upgraded my BIOS to the newest version (despite it was not necessary). Please look at my screenshots to see what happens when I try to load any LIVECD linux distros or install linux'es on my PC. I tried some methods and have some info about few of these issues, but it's not enough to make them disappear. Maybe it's a problem with compatibility with the new system, or...

..I don't know, maybe someone could suggest some solutions ?

Thanks in advance..

Links to screenshots:

https://plus.google.com/photos/109268532892116210569/albums/5974420098432532705

**I've added a MemTest screenshot to the gallery. I'll make new tests and upload them soon..**

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and for which architecture are you trying to install? Which installation medium are you using? And can you retrieve the logs for the CLI and post them here (instead of screenshots)?

Comment: The photos show a lot of "firmware bug", memory errors,... - faulty hardware?

Comment: @landroni Ubuntu 12,13.04 - both 64bit architecture. Mediums I used are: DVD's, which I burned myself, and flashback (pendrive). There were no problems with installing any of these systems, on any other hardware. I can try to get logs, but usually the system freezes while booting, showing processor registry entries... [quntbert]: Yep, that's right. This I know. I thought about memory issue, and even tested with MemTest, and it showed me loads of red errors. But.. I have no problem with rams on my systems installed (winXP and Ubuntu 10.04 x86). And I wonder if its ram or ram socket issue.

Comment: Ahh... Apparently this was my RAM issue. I couldn't first believe it, but it's true, unfortunately. So the problem solved. MemTest tested my RAM's one by one and two of the four are the rubbish now.. :( but thanks for your suggestions, they were very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a memory problem to me. I had the same problem on 2 computers.
In my case, there was a range in the memory that was faulty. I guess in your case, this is after 4GiB, so 32 Bit does not access it.

I would recommend to run memtest, which is available within the boot menu of the ubuntu installer disc.

Comment: Ater testing you're fully right! Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunaltely two/of four RAM's can be abandoned now...